# How does Nginx pass request to backends?

Tags: nginx

I am confused about Nginx HTTP proxying process.  How does Nginx handle the request, and pass it to backends?  For example, I post a file to Nginx, does Nginx save the whole file into a tmp dir first then pass it to backends ? Or just pass the request immediately?

Comment: Hi Anson, please upvote and accept my answer below if it helped you with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx will `proxy` the full request, meaning it will do the request on your behalf and respond with the headers/content it got back from the request. This keeps it transparent to the client.

In terms of buffering the client request, it depends on the size. If its small, it will buffer in memory, but larger requests will be stored to filesystem temporarily:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_buffer_size

additional information: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Got it, thanks!  One more question, if the connection between client and Nginx is broken while Nginx is sending the request to backends, what will happen with the request?

Comment: if the request to the client (you) is broken, then that means the tcp stack of the nginx server retries to receive your acks then gives up and tears down the connection. if the request to the backend is broken then the client (you) will most likely receive a 502 response (bad gateway)

Comment: By the first situation you just said, does it mean  that  nginx and backends will keep handling the request no matter the connection between client and nginx is or not broken?

Comment: `HTTP` is **stateless**. Nginx will make the call once to the backend and buffer the response until you get it or the connection drops. Depending on your configuration and the request, nginx may also cache the response for better performance (such as static content), but that's a whole other topic.